# state not accessible in componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently learning React Hooks.

I was trying to access state value into my class component's componentDidUpdate() function, however it is not showing up and I am not able to figure out why. On the contrary, the same state value is accessible in the componentDidMount() function.

Can somebody please help me to understand what might be the problem and its possible solution because the  same example is working fine on the youtube tutorial ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAuWOnFMlOw&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwisvxhZ135pogtX7_Oe3Q3A&index=7)) I am referring to.

Link to CodeSandBox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/06reacthooksuseeffect-s448c)

Sample Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ClassCounter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Clicked {this.state.count} times.";
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    document.title = "Clicked {this.state.count} times.";
    alert("Clicked ${this.state.count} times.");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>From Class Component.</p>
        <p>You clicked {this.state.count} number of times.</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
          Clicked {this.state.count} times.
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ClassCounter;
```

Comment: Voting to close due to typo in string templating, `document.title = "Clicked {this.state.count} times.";` versus `document.title = \`Clicked ${this.state.count} times.\`;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string interpolation syntax in `componentDidMount` and in `componentDidUpdate` is wrong.
The correct syntax:

```js
document.title = `Clicked ${this.state.count} times.`;
```

Notice the backtick ( ` ) and the $ characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax, use **``**

```
    componentDidMount() {
    document.title = `Clicked ${this.state.count} times.`;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    document.title = `Clicked ${this.state.count} times.`;
    alert(`Clicked ${this.state.count} times.`);
  }
```